# How to pass data from native android to react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to pass one string value from native android Main Activity class to react native component. I apply this code, but once I print the "data" in the log it shows undefined. I am not able to understand what is the problem. I am a beginner in react native. Thanks in advance.

In Main Activity:

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {

                Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
                initialProperties.putString("var_1","Im the first var");
                return initialProperties;
            }
        };
    }
```

In App.js:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    var data = this.props.var_1;
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>{this.props.var_1}</Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There are several ways:

You can send it by emitting event from android activity and handle that event in your react component.

```
    //Emitting the event from Android Activity.

    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
            map.putString("key1", "Value1");
            map.putString("key1", "Value1");

        try {
           getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()   
          .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
          .emit("customEventName", map);

            } catch (Exception e){
              Log.e("ReactNative", "Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

And in react component addEventListner(subscribe) to that event like as:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

componentWillMount: function() {
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('customEventName', function(e: Event) {
    // handle event and you will get a value in event object, you can log it here
  });
}
```

---

Another way is:

You can store that string in SharedPreferences and can access the same value from the React-native component.
Refer below link for the shared preferences use:
https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences

Comment: Thanks for reply. But its not working!! Any other way?

Comment: You can refer official doc here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-shared-preferences:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.  This is the error showing when I added dependency - compile project(":react-native-shared-preferences")

Comment: I thought there is an error because of the link of react-native library.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Now it's working!! https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-shared-preferences

Comment: You are a life saver.. Thankyou!
Sending events wasn't working for me in release apk for some odd reason. I then used shared prefs to pass data on your suggestion, and it worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-android) has several ways to do this.

The one similar to your code using is overriding `ReactActivityDelegate`.

Make sure you include the relevant imports. I was not using Android Studio and it was not done automatically which caused few errors.

Add these imports to android/app/src/main/java/APPNAME/MainActivity.java:

```java
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Then add the override method to the body of MainActivity class:

```java
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                "http://example.com/bar1.png",
                "http://example.com/bar2.png"
        ));
        initialProperties.putStringArrayList("images", imageList);
        return initialProperties;
      }
    };
  }
```

Then in your App.js you can access `props.images` (images property was added through MainAcitivity. You can name it whatever you want).

This example is using functional component. You can see class based example in the linked documentation.

```js
import React from 'react';
function App(props) {
    console.log('APP PROPS', props.images);
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that the ReactActivityDelegate, onCreate, and getLaunchOptions are called before onCreate in the main Activity. And the bundle passed to delegate's onCreate is null, even when a non-null is subsequently passed to Activity's onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option that is highlighted in the React Native / Native Modules (Android) documentation.

It's Callbacks!

You can pass a callback as a function in your client (js) code and invoke it in the Java module with the data you want to return.

You need to import the Callback bridge module in your Java class:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
```

Then your method declaration:

```
public class YourModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

...

  @ReactMethod
  public void customMethod(int param, Callback callback) {
    try {
      // do something 
      callback.invoke("Your data"); // Invoke the callback here
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // exception code here
    }
  }

...
```

Then in your Java code, you can invoke the callback

And now you can pass callback from you js code like so:

```
YourModule.customMethod(1, (data) => {})
```