# how to send data from android application running on kotlin to a react js application which is opened on webview?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, kotlin

Suppose you are running an android application (kotlin) and u have logged in and have some data. Then in webview you open a react js application.
How can u pass that login data from android to react js application.

Comment: look this issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089235/how-to-pass-data-from-native-android-to-react-native/54089436

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this personally, but I believe you would want to package any data you have inside of a script tag and inject it into the web view. For example, if the React application needs the value of `user_id` you would pass in the user id to a script like:

```kotlin
val script = """
    <script> var user_id = ${user.id} </script>
"""
```

Because I'm not a React guy, that may not work right off the bat. You might need to add the value to the `document` object and read it off that way.

Once the script is created then you can include it into your webview using the [`loadDataWithBaseURL` function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). It would look something like this:

```kotlin
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(reactAppUrl, script, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```